# Minimize an if-else condition

Tags: javascript

I'm learning ES6, i want to know if it's possible to minimize an if-else condition:

```
if (isCreated.length > 0) {
          isConnected = true
        }
        else {  
          isConnected = false
        }
        person.isConnected = isConnected
      }}
```

Is there a way to do this with a ternary Operator ?

Comment: `person.isConnected = isCreated.length > 0;`

Comment: try with this: person.isConnected = (isCreated.length > 0)

Answer (score 4):

```
person.isConnected = isCreated.length > 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, don't know why i get downvoted for wanting to learn a new way to do things

Answer (score 2):

You could use a double logical not, which uses a truthy/falsy value and converts it to a boolean value.

```
person.isConnected = !!isCreated.length;
```

For an explicit conversion, you could use either a check

```
person.isConnected = isCreated.length > 0;
```

or `Boolean` as function.

```
person.isConnected = Boolean(isCreated.length);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, don't know why i get downvoted for wanting to learn a new way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to change that to ternary like this:

```
person.isConnected = isCreated.length > 0 ? true : false;
```

But as stated here by Kristoffer and Nina, it can be done in shorter manner:

```
person.isConnected = isCreated.length > 0;
```

or even shorter:

```
person.isConnected = !!isCreated.length;
```